# How to detect the accuracy margin of error using Core Location

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I have an app that tracks user location using the following:

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

According to Apple's documentation, Core Location will try to obtain the best possible reading until I tell it to stop. However, I realize the reading can be impaired by many uncontrollable things i.e. weather, device in a building, etc.

For the purposes of my app, I would like to store how accurate the reading actually was. For example, if I am in a field, I may get a reading that is accurate up to 10 meters, but if I were in that same field during a thunderstorm, I may get a reading that is accurate up to 100 meters.

Is there a way to detect how accurate my reading actually is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLLocation` (the object that gets returned from the `CLLocationManager`) contains two properties, `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy`.

This is a value measured in metres that tells you how many metres radius around the given location you could be.

You can read more about `CLLocation` here... [CLLocation Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)

I believe this is what Apple uses in its maps app to place the circle around the location to represent the area you could possibly be in.